# python 2.7.6 evaluating capitalization in strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I need to evaluate if the first letter in a string is capitalized. How do you do this? The program reads:

```
String = raw_input ('Please enter a string. ')
```

Not sure how to finish this out. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.isupper`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.isupper):

```
>>> 'Hello'[:1].isupper()
True
>>> 'hello'[:1].isupper()
False
>>> ''[:1].isupper()
False
```

Comment: How would i incorporate that into if/elif/else statements then? Suppose if the string turns out to be true, print this. elif it is false print that.

Comment: @jak10101, `if String[:1].isupper(): ....`

Comment: wouldn'y hello[0] be enuf? why [:1]??

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, not to cause IndexError for empty string.